# Naming an attribute to indicate it should recieve a value from 0 to 1

Tags: names

Warning: this is a vanity question

I dislike percentages in the innards of program logic. Yet they have this useful um.. quality that people assume they should enter from 0 to 100, a fixed range of values. If I were to write this function:

```
int GiveMeFiveMaybe(int PercentSuccess) {
    int r = rand() % 100;
    if (r < PercentSuccess) return 5;
    return 6;
}
```

Then whoever looks at this after me would assume that the meaningful range of options to enter in the PercentSuccess attribute would run from 0 to 100, just by looking at the function declaration.

Yet ifI want something that is between 0 and 1 though, like over here:

```
int GiveMeFiveMaybeFancy(double SuccessChance) {
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> unif(0, 1);
    std::default_random_engine re;
    double r = unif(re);
    if (r < SuccessChance) return 5;
    return 6;
}
```

Then "SuccessChance" is kinda ambiguous and the developer would have to read the documentation, ugh!

I mean.. I'm all for well documented libraries but I also appreciate it if the developer has also gone through the extra trouble to make the names of things a guide to your intuition.

Yes, asking these hard questions is what coding is all about.. anyways, is there a word for indicating that something should contain a value from 0 to 1?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use "PerUnit" in place of "Percent".

Although "perunit" is neither an English word nor a common expression, the parallel construction and Latin roots should make it clear that you mean "[out] of 1" rather than "[out] of 100".